# MS Word: How to remove all tables?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I need to run text-check program on my doc (Grammarly), and I need to remove all the tables.

How can I do it?

I find https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/1208-word-remove-delete-all-tables.html , in which you could use VBA

```
Sub Removetables ()
Dim oTable As Table
Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
oTable.Delete
Next oTable
End Sub
```

but `Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables` gives me error when I run it. I'm on MS Word 2013 on Mac

Comment: You can select any table and then go to Layout tab under Table tools, then click on Convert to Text. This will delete the tables and make them a plain text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing the `For` in `For Each`:

```
Sub Removetables ()
    Dim oTable As Table
    For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    oTable.Delete
    Next oTable
End Sub
```

Comment: Didn't thought it could be this simple. I'm not familiar with VBA sytax at all.

Comment: You may wish to run through the tables backwards, deleting from the end.

Comment: @Lobachevsky, why is that? Won't the For Each iterate through even if one is deleted? Or does it do some weird renumbering or something?

Comment: @Jake Pages re-arrangement ... (I suppose)...  Word loves to express his _creativity_ with the space rearrangement (Images that change page and so on...)`:)`. Starting from up you allow _him( Word )_ to do it more times... _(n*(n-1)/2)_ with _n_ tables, instead of _n_.